# I can't run command "composer require classiebit/addchat-laravel-pro" on godady hosting server

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I bought source code from https://codecanyon.net/item/addchat-laravel-pro/25750268 and tried to install on my hosting server.

My hosting server is godady.

https://addchat-laravel-pro-docs.classiebit.com/docs/1.1/installation

This is install guide of addchat.

With putty, in terminal, I run the command `https://addchat-laravel-pro-docs.classiebit.com/docs/1.1/installation` and after that, I can see picture as follow;

If you have experience with addchat-laravel-pro and godady, please let me know.

I hope your help.

Thanks

when I run command "free -m", I can see picture as follow;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

---

You got the following error on your production server after using `composer require classiebit/addchat-laravel-pro`.

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

Because your server is running out of memory.

**Solution:**

---

1. You need to upgrade your server to one with more RAM.
2. You should install that package first on your local development server and `git push` to your remote server. Once you have git pulled on your production server you should run `composer install` rather than `composer update`.

**UPDATED:**

```
$>which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer

$>php -d memory_limit=512M /usr/local/bin/composer require classiebit/addchat-laravel-pro
```

**UPDATED AGAIN:**

The solution is to use the COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT environment variable, setting its value to -1. It can be added to the current Terminal session with

```
$ export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
```

After

```
$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require classiebit/addchat-laravel-pro
```

**UPDATED (2020/12/20):**

I see that `49930 MB` memory are cached. You could try [flush the memory cache](https://tecadmin.net/flush-memory-cache-on-linux-server/) on your system.

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: can you help me with my problem on my server directly?

Comment: if you have experience, can you help me on my server directly?

Comment: Does it work? If not, you try another way. I updated my post.

Comment: I have already tried, but result is the same

Comment: Could you please share the output after using `free -m`?

Comment: I see that `49930 MB` memory are cached. You could try flush the memory cache on your system. https://tecadmin.net/flush-memory-cache-on-linux-server/. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to upgrade to composer v2, it's very fast.

Try:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require PACKAGE_NAME
```